# Understand "work" in "they don't work either"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I saw this tweet and tried to understand it:

> My daughter asked me if Socialism doesn't work, why do people support it? I said because they don't **work** either.

Per my understanding, in the first sentence, "Socialism doesn't work", probably means "Socialism isn't good for people". But I haven't find a way to interpret the word "work" in the second sentence, or what "they don't work" stands for.

Answer (score 3):

This is a play on two different meanings of *work*.

In *socialism doesn't work*, the word *work* is used to refer to something that functions or succeeds. The Macmillan Dictionary definition reads

> [intransitive] to operate in a satisfactory way
>
> > The new telephone system seems to be working perfectly.
> >      This pen doesn’t work.
> >      My brain’s not working very well today.

The *they* in *they don't work either* refers to people who support socialism, and *work* is in the sense of

> [intransitive] to have a job, usually one that you are paid to do
>
> > Dominic works part-time.

In other words, to paraphrase, *the only people who think socialism is a functional system are people who do not have jobs*. The statement is not meant to be factual, but rather might be repeated by someone on the political right to cast aspersion wryly on people who support socialism as being disconnected from the discipline of work: students and academicians, the unemployable, celebrities and the [idle rich](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/champagne-socialist), the lazy, and so forth.

Comment: I work very hard and I support socialism.Stupid tweet.

Comment: It's a Tweet. What do you expect? You don't get wisdom from bumper stickers, either.